# Socket IO Client won't connect to Streamlabs Server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I just started working with the Socket IO library and I pulled this fairly simple code off the internet, and it doesn't see to connect to the Streamlabs server. It just outputs 5 and then outputs ping timeout every 30 seconds afterwards. (Pulled some of the code from this example: https://dev.streamlabs.com/docs/socket-api)

````
const streamlabs = io(`https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=${socketToken}`, {transports: ['websocket']});
  

streamlabs.on("connect", () => {
    console.log(10)
});

streamlabs.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
  console.log(reason)
});
console.log(5)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the [dcoumentation](https://dev.streamlabs.com/docs/getting-started), first of all you should get `socketToken`
You can get started with the Streamlabs API in three simple steps.

1. Register your application
2. Connect user(s) to your account
3. Use your access_token and execute API calls